# Intuition of vector of $n$ dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra

Actually I was reading Lectures of Physics by Feynman where he introuduced gradient theorem. While I was googling about this theorem, I came across vector of $n$ dimensions. I'm having a great problem in understanding this. What does it mean, when we say a vector has $n$ components? What is the direction? I really need a good intuition.

Comment: Imagine a vector with $3$ components, then imagine $n - 3$ more! In all seriousness, in the finite-dimensional case, that's pretty much what works for me; just imagine $3$-space, but always leave open the possibility that "more" can be happening. And forget about the cross-product, it's a freak occurrence for $3$-space.

Comment: @psj36: I saw at the math insight that 6-dimensional vector is used for locating rigid body like an aeroplane. And many more for non-rigid bodies. Don't all these components have direction?

Comment: Not every vector necessarily has a sensible or meaningful "direction" in the geometric sense.  What we can say, though, is that certain directions "line up" to a certain extent. The dot product (or more generally any inner product) is a good measure of how well two vectors "line up".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mathematically a vector isn't really an arrow, just an element of a set, called vector space, whose elements can basically be added together and multiplied with a number the usual way.

There are no geometric concepts in a vector space, except for colinearity. We can always say, that if $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ (or any other field for that matter, but let us just look at the reals) then if $x,y\in V$ then those two vectors are colinear iff $y=\alpha x$, where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ is some appropriate number.

Any other concept of geometry comes from additional structures you introduce on your vector space, such as a norm, an inner product, a symplectic form, etc. Depending on what structure you impose, the geometry induced might be like euclidean geometry (inner product) or completely alien (symplectic form for example).

The dimension of a vector space is basically just the amount of "degrees of freedom" in the vector space, nothing about directions.

Since you spoke of rigid bodies, let me use them as an example. In classical mechanics, the so called configuration space of a rigid body is the set $\mathbb{R}^3\times SO(3)$, where $\mathbb{R}^3$ is the usual euclidean 3-space, and $SO(3)$ is something called the special orthogonal group. This is basically the set of all rotations of the euclidean 3-space. It is **not** a vector space, but it is a set that *can be continuously parametrized by a triple of numbers*, so it is similiar enough that I can use it as an example.

Usually this representation of $SO(3)$ is done by specifying three angles. Therefore, a rigid body's state at any time can be specified by giving the 6-tuple $$ (x(t),y(t),z(t),\alpha(t),\beta(t),\gamma(t)). $$
The first three of these refer to the rigid body's position in space, the second three refers to the rigid body's *orientation* in space.

As you can see, a rigid body has six degrees of freedom, so one can be described by tuples of 6 numbers. These also carry geometric data, since it gives both spatial position and orientation. There is absolutely no sense in assigning *directions* or *length* to this tuple though (and since the addition of two such tuples is meaningless, they are not even vectors really).

EDIT:
Here is an expansion of my comment, in response to yours, since the character limit on comments prevents me to post a meaningful answer.

Imagine the equation for a circle of radius $a$ in the plane. This usually takes the form $$ x^2+y^2=a^2, $$ however if I write $$ r=a, $$ this equation also means the same thing.

Two different equations describe the same thing!

To describe a *point* on the circle of radius $a$, I need to specify an $x$ and $y$ value that obeys my first equation. But a circle is what we call a one-dimensional manifold, it is parametrizable by one parameter. The equation $x^2+y^2=a^2$ provides a *constrait* on the parameters $x$ and $y$, that reduces the *degrees of freedom* in specifying a point on the circle to one parameter.

This one parameter can be an angle for example $\varphi$.

The reason why the abstract formalism exists in linear algebra is to be able to express geometric *data* in a way that is invariant of any *representation* of said data.
In my example, both $x^2+y^2=a^2$ and $r=a$ is a concrete representation of a circle.
When we actually calculate something, we use representations, that depend on a particular coordinate system. When we want to *formulate* something, we can do so abstractly, that *directly* means something geometrical. And by geometrical, I don't mean *euclidean* specifically, so it doesn't necessary have anything to do with actual angles or lengths or anything.

When a real vector space, $V$ is for example, 6 dimensional, it means that an element $x$ of $V$, when assigned to a representation, will have 6 **independent** components. Six independent number is needed to actually give the data encoded in the single vector, $x$. The degrees of freedom in the $V$ space is 6. The space $V$ can be an euclidean vector space, in which case, the six data represents multidimensional "directions" and lengths, yes. But it can carry *any* other kinds of data that needs six numbers to be specified.

Comment: +1 for your statement that vector is not mere arrow. Sir, if you don't mind if I ask you  what you actually meant by "degrees of freedom". How do "degrees of freedom" correspond to direction in $\mathbf{R}^3$ ? Can you please explain??

Comment: @user36790 No matter how abstract you go with linear algebra (and this is coming from someone who vastly prefers abstract formalism), vectors and operators are basically ways to encode systems of equations describing linear relations into less cumbersome objects that when treated abstractly also possess standalone geometric meaning. What I meant by degrees of freedom is that a certain amount of data, expressible by real or complex numbers will be encoded into linear algebraic objects. The dimension of a vector space is the amount of numeric data encoded in an arbitrary element of the space.

Comment: @user36790 Edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

The most familiar $n$-dimensional vector space that look like a 'typical' vector space is undoubtedly $\Bbb R^n = \{(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) : x_i \in \Bbb R\}$, the space of of all *tuples* consisting of $n$ real numbers.

As a hands-on simplified stand-in for $\Bbb R^n$, your best bet is probably $3$-space, $\Bbb R^3$. In $\Bbb R^3$, each component of a vector represents a distinct 'direction' (as well as a length), and all of our 'pure' directions, like $(0, 0, 1)$, are at right angles to all other pure directions, like $(1, 0, 0)$. Any given vector, say $(3, -1, 2)$, specifies something pointing $3$ units in the $x_1$ direction, backwards $1$ unit in the $x_2$ direction, and $2$ units in the $x_3$ direction.

In $\Bbb R^n$, the same line of reasoning is perfectly good, except instead of only having $3$ 'pure' directions, we have $n$ of them, all still at right angles to one another. With the vector $(2, 5, -2, 1, -5) \in \Bbb R^5$, we can decompose it into 'pure' directions, just like we did in $\Bbb R^3$; we just have more of them now.

If all of your vectors will always be from some Euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$, then congratulations, you are officially working with the nicest space I can think of! This need not be the case though; there are plenty of different kinds of $n$-dimensional vector spaces, and even infinite-dimensional spaces that show up throughout math and physics. Most of them are not as nice as $\Bbb R^n$; 'direction' may not mean what it does in $\Bbb R^n$, we may not be given a natural way to speak of 'length', or the 'length' may look completely unlike the length of a line-segment, to name some basic differences.

However, a solid understanding of Linear Algebra will enable you to understand the similarities and differences among spaces, and work reasonably comfortably in almost any vector space you can dream up.

Comment: Thanks, sir, for the answers. So, a vector of $n$ dimensions has $n$ components in $n$ directions; are these directions orthogonal? And, sir, what should be the definition of a vector because it is much more than an arrow? Can I not tell it is an ordered pair??

Comment: [Here](http://mathinsight.org/n_dimensional_vector_examples), vector of 9-dimensions has been used to define the angle of its parts. Now, do the angles have any direction? Mean to say can I define direction always for vector of higher dimensions??

Comment: @user36790 It all depends on the vector space. If you're in $\Bbb R^n$ and talking about the standard basis vectors, yes, they're all orthogonal ("at right angles"). In those examples, it's probably **not** appropriate to think of the angles as having a meaningful direction *as vectors in the space*. I would recommend an Linear Algebra book; Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right* can be found online and will lay down "what vectors are", although I learned from Lay's *Linear Algebra* as a much more down-to-earth standard text.

Comment: Thanks, sir , for the book reference. Vector  dimensions are the "degrees of freedom" that defines the state of the measured quantity.